# Extract between html tag with unknown tagname?

Tags: java, regex

```
<b>Topic1</b><ul>asdasd</ul><br/><b>Topic2</b><ul>....
```

I want to extract everything that comes after `<b>Topic1</b>` and the next `<b>` starting tag. Which in this case would be: `<ul>asdasd</ul><br/>`.

Problem: it must not necessairly be the `<b>` tag, but could be any other repeating tag.

So my question is: how can I dynamically extract those text? The only static thinks are:

- The signal keyword to look for is always "Topic1". I'd like to take the surrounding tags as the one to look for.
- The tag is always repeated. In this case it's always `<b>`, it might as well be `<i>` or `<strong>` or `<h1>` etc.

I know how to write the java code, but what would the regex be like?

```
String regex = ">Topic1<";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(m.group(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Obligatory attempt to put you off using regex to parse HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @AndyTurner as the content I want to parse might also be corrupt html formatting, I think in this case any java xml parser would fail. So I have to stick to regex.

Comment: You could do something like `<(\w+)>Topic1<\/\1>` to match different tags.    Will it always be followed by another Topic?  If not, is the only other scenario the end of the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work

```
Topic1</(.+?)>(.*?)<\\1>
```

Input: `<b>Topic1</b><ul>asdasd</ul><br/><b>Topic2</b><ul>`

Output: `<ul>asdasd</ul><br/>`

Code:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Topic1</(.+?)>(.*?)<\\1>");
    //  get a matcher object
    Matcher m = p.matcher("<b>Topic1</b><ul>asdasd</ul><br/><b>Topic2</b><ul>");
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(2));  // <ul>asdasd</ul><br/>
    }
```

Comment: Great, that seems close. What if the input string might be distributed over several lines, thus contain linebreaks? How could I make the `*` operator also match anything, whatever it is, even line breaks?

Comment: In that case use `Pattern.compile("<pattern>", Pattern.DOTALL);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String pattern = "\\<.*?\\>Topic1\\<.*?\\>"; // this will see the tag no matter what tag it is
String text = "<b>Topic1</b><ul>asdasd</ul><br/><b>Topic2</b>"; // your string to be split
String[] attributes = text.split(pattern);
for(String atr : attributes) 
{
    System.out.println(atr);
}
```

Will print out:

```
<ul>asdasd</ul><br/><b>Topic2</b>
```